# Both Pages are Displaying its content on a single page - React

Tags: reactjs

Hey I am a Smart Contract Developer first time using react and when I try to switch pages using Router both pages Data are showing on a single page, I wanna ask is there some way to first load main page and when I click on another button the data of another page show.

App.js:

```
<Router>
    <Link className="btn-success user-btn" to = "/user">User Login</Link>
    <Link className="btn-success admin-btn">Admin Login</Link>
    <Switch>
     <Route path={"/user"} exact>
      <User />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

User.js:

```
import React from 'react';
const User = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
            User Panel
        </div>
    );
}
export default User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Component is the main component in React which acts as a container for all other components. When you put some content in there, it will show up everywhere in your app. You can simply create another component, let's name it Home

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
          <Link className="btn-success user-btn" to = "/user">User Login</Link>
          <Link className="btn-success admin-btn">Admin Login</Link>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

**App.js**

```
import User from './User';
import Home from './Home';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home}></Route>
          <Route exact path={"/user"} component={User}></Route>
        </Switch>
     </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes thanks bro it is working, but when I click user button it doesn't go to user page I have to reload page every time to load user page

Comment: I have run your app on my local and I haven't encountered any issues. Have you altered any other part of the app or maybe forgot something? 
These are my imports in app.js, Home.js and User.js are in the same folder as App.js

`import { Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';`
`import User from './User';`
`import Home from './Home';`